# How optimaze a numpy loop with spline interpolate (scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, time, scipy

I have been trying to optimize a loop in numpy. Now the loop runs in 26s. I would like to know if it is possible reduce this time.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy.matlib as matlib


I=10000
T=10000
ct = np.zeros((I,T))
x = matlib.repmat(np.linspace(0,25,I).reshape(I,1),1,T) 
y = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (I,T))
x1 = matlib.repmat(np.linspace(2,20,I).reshape(I,1),1,T) 

tck0 = interpolate.splrep(x[:,0], y[:,0], s=0)
tck1 = interpolate.splrep(x[:,1], y[:,1], s=0)

for t in range(T):
    ct[:,t] = (y[:,t]<=5)*interpolate.splev(x1[:,t], tck0, der=0, ext=0) + \
              (y[:,t]>5)*interpolate.splev(x1[:,t], tck1, der=0, ext=0)
```

Comment: Your code is unclear. What is the point of X having T columns if you only use the first? What is the point of y[:,t]<=5 or >5? For both case you're assigning the same value? Otherwise you can simply say ct=interpolate.splev(x1, tck0, der=0, ext=0) which took about 10 seconds on my pc.

Comment: You are correct. I fix the code.

Comment: Can `interpolate.splev` work with a 2d `x1`, either all of it, or a subset?  The best way to improve the speed is to replace 10000 calls to `interpolate.splev` with one or just a few.  I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `BSpline` instance with the splrep output, and use a single vectorized call instead of splev loops.